# Clearing QTableView in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreeview

I am working with PyQt5 and I am trying to clear a QTreeView by pressing a button. The program is supposed to take a path from the user with a QLineEdit and then display it on the TreeView. So far it's working great. The thing is that I can't figure out how to clear the view once I'm finished or maybe if I typed in the wrong path. I know that I could just use the clear() function but it works only with a Widget, not with a View. If I use the reset() function it just displays the "This PC" folder without completey clearing the Tree.
I am going to include the code just in case.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
import sys


class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Init UI
        self.tree = qtw.QTreeView()
        self.model = qtw.QFileSystemModel()

        # Items
        self.path_input = qtw.QLineEdit()
        path_label = qtw.QLabel("Enter a path to begin: ")
        check_btn = qtw.QPushButton("Check")  # To display the items
        clear_btn = qtw.QPushButton("Clear")  # To clear the TreeView
        start_btn = qtw.QPushButton("Start")  # Not implemented yet

        # Layouts
        top_h_layout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        top_h_layout.addWidget(path_label)
        top_h_layout.addWidget(self.path_input)
        top_h_layout.addWidget(check_btn)
        bot_h_layout = qtw.QHBoxLayout()
        bot_h_layout.addWidget(clear_btn)
        bot_h_layout.addWidget(start_btn)
        main_v_layout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        main_v_layout.addLayout(top_h_layout)
        main_v_layout.addWidget(self.tree)
        main_v_layout.addLayout(bot_h_layout)
        self.setLayout(main_v_layout)

        check_btn.clicked.connect(self.init_model)
        clear_btn.clicked.connect(self.clear_model)

        self.show()

    def init_model(self):
        self.model.setRootPath(self.path_input.text())
        self.tree.setModel(self.model)
        self.tree.setRootIndex(self.model.index(self.path_input.text()))

    def clear_model(self):
        self.tree.reset()  # This is where I get the problem


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "clear a view", as the view only shows the model's content, it cannot *directly* modify (or "clear") it. Also, [`reset()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#reset) does not do what you're trying to achieve:

> ### void QAbstractItemView::reset()
>
> Reset the internal state of the view.

The *state*, not the model. As you can see, in your case it only resets the root node in its collapsed state.

What you need to clear is the model, but since you clearly cannot clear a filesystem model, the solution is to set the view's state *as it was before starting the search*: by *removing* the model from the view.

```
    def clear_model(self):
        self.tree.setModel(None)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I'm still new to PyQt so I don't really get the difference between Widgets and Views

Comment: @Simon In short, [QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#details) is the base element of an user interface, each widget can contain many child widgets (possibly nested in multiple levels of layouts and other child widgets), and could also be "top level widgets" (as in "window"). In fact, QMainWindow inherits from QWidget. Item views are more complex widgets that are able to [show the content of a data model](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html), they generally are subclasses of a scroll area, and use abstract objects known as *delegates* to actually show/manage the data.